# Active Directory Account Password Expiration Date with Fine-Grain Password Policy

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm having no issue getting the password expiration date in a pre-Windows 2008 domain envrionment.  I'm able to get the default domain policy and get the password expiration date.

However, in 2008 and up they added a feature for Fine-Grain Password Policies.  Essentially more than one password policy may be in effect for a specific user account.

Does anyone have any resources or sample code that takes into account these new FGPP and how I can incorporate them into my existing script?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to look at the `msDS-ResultantPSO` constructed attribute on the specific user in question and get the DN of the password settings object that applies to the user. From there, you can look at the expiry setting on the PSO and combine it with the `pwdLastSet` value on the user.

If the `msDS-ResultantPSO` attribute is null on the user, then you should fall back to the domain password policy.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is almost 4 years old but I wanted to add the code that I got working to solve a similar problem. Additionally, if you aren't able to read from the PSO you need to make sure the user running your code has Read permissions on the PSO in question (this is what caused me the most trouble).

```
var ad = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, _domain, _ldapPathOu);

UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ad, username);
DirectoryEntry entry = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
SearchResultCollection results;
mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msDS-ResultantPSO");

results = mySearcher.FindAll();

if (results.Count >= 1)
{
    string pso = results[0].Properties["msDS-ResultantPSO"][0].ToString();

    //do something with the pso..
    DirectoryEntry d = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://corp.example.com/"+ pso);

    var searchForPassPolicy = new DirectorySearcher(d);
    searchForPassPolicy.Filter = @"(objectClass=msDS-PasswordSettings)";
    searchForPassPolicy.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree;

    searchForPassPolicy.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new string[] {"msDS-MaximumPasswordAge"});
    var x = searchForPassPolicy.FindAll();

    var maxAge = (Int64)x[0].Properties["msDS-MaximumPasswordAge"][0];
    var maxPwdAgeInDays = ConvertTimeToDays(maxAge);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment on @foldinglettuce's answer, I'll provide it in my own answer.

First, you don't need to escape forward slashes as you do for `DirectoryEntry` with an "@". It's not required and should be removed.

Second, you ask for the `msDS-ResultantPSO` property to be loaded, excellent. Then you check to make sure a user was found with `if (results.Count >= 1)`, again excellent. Now's where you fail...what if that property is null (and therefore not included)? you can't `.ToString()`. You need to follow up with a check for that. It should look like something like this...

```
if (results.Count >= 1)
{
    if(results[0].Properties.Contains("msDS-ResultantPSO"))
    {
       // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After much mulling around the internet, looking for answers and not finding much, I created this command that worked for us in PowerShell (modify OUPath to your AD OU):

```
$OUpath = 'ou=Users,dc=company,dc=local'

$ExportPath = 'c:\temp\pwexpiry.csv'

Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OUpath -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} –Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | 

Select-Object -Property "Displayname",@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}} | Export-Csv -NoType $ExportPath
```

This will give you a nice CSV file of the fine grained password expiration dates of a specific OU.